# Netbeans 7.2 is generating erroneous Javadoc without css

Tags: javadoc, netbeans-7

After upgrading to Netbeans 7.2 (64-bit), I can't get properly generated javadocs. There is no css and there are non-ascii characters as in the image:[image: index.html of javadoc]

I believe it is something about the `<html lang="tr">` line. Because the `ı` character in the keywords `script` and `title` is a Turkish character. And its capital version is `I`. I'm on Windows 7 Turkish by the way.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Tags cannot be understood by the browser since tags (script or title) contains Turkish letter.
Did you try to add additional parameter?

```
Projects > Properties > Build > Documenting > Additional Javadoc Options: -locale en_US
```

Then regenerate the javadoc.

Comment: Since with NB 7.4 the problem is solved, I'm not goint to try your solution. However it may have worked though. Anyways +1 for the effort.